# Faster way of iterating through the map and matching pattern in the keys

Tags: java, performance, java-8

I have a map as shown below(simpleMap). **Keys and values in this map change at runtime**. I want to read the keys and look for existence of a string in the keys as shown below:

```
    Map<String, String> simpleMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    simpleMap.put("language","GB");
    simpleMap.put("locale","GB");
    simpleMap.put("paging","");
    simpleMap.put("source","Next_act");
    simpleMap.put("Wizard-SectionSelection-0-Selected","");
    simpleMap.put("Wizard-SectionSelection-2-Selected","");
    simpleMap.put("Wizard-SectionSelection-9-Selected","");`
```

If any of the keys of simpleMap contains "SectionSelection" then I will return true else false as shown below.

```
    private boolean myMethod(Map<String, String> simpleMap) {
        for (String temp : simpleMap.keySet()) {
           if(temp.contains("SectionSelection")) {
                return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: How may time `myMethod()` will call? If many time then preprocessing can make it faster otherwise it seems okay to me

Comment: This method is called for each and every action performed in my application.

Comment: What kinds of substrings will you be searching for? If it's a fixed set, you could store a multimap from those strings to the matching values. If it's really just any arbitrary substring of the keys then you're not going to do better than O(n).

Comment: I just noticed, you only need to tell if the key is present (you return a boolean). Does the map change often? You could concatenate all the keys and check if the string appears in that concatenated string, or maybe do something involving a trie or suffix tree or something. I would rethink this design, though.

Comment: Map is dynamic and so the keys will change.. All that I want to do is search "SectionSelection" substring in the keys.

Comment: "SectionSelection" is fixed ? If yes then use a counter ,when update map also update counter checking new string contains or not.

Comment: You talk about "SectionSelection" but you show looking for "LOBSelectionScreen".  This is confusing.

Comment: Can you use the method `containsKey` from Map instead of `contains` from String? Thus, you will not need use a `for`.

Comment: @JoãoZarate he's looking for a substring of the key (I think).

Comment: @WJS, you're right. In this particular case, I think the same that Eklavya, seems ok to me.

Comment: Corrected the string. "SectionSelection"

Comment: There is no "more efficient" way of doing this with a Map. It's a Map, and they work the way they work. If this is a true bottle neck in your application, then you need to look at different data structures to manifest the search, or different representations so as not to have to search at all. You may have several indexes, rather than just one perhaps. "SectionSelection" could be a state of the underlying data rather than relying on free form text to capture it, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop through the set of keys is extremely lightweight both in terms of heap and CPU usage. Therefore, if you are concerned about the performance, you should stick to the definition which you have posted.

If you are looking for succinct ways, given below are some examples:

```
private boolean myMethod(Map<String, String> simpleMap) {
    return simpleMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(key -> key.contains("SectionSelection"));
}
```

or

```
private boolean myMethod(Map<String, String> simpleMap) {
    return String.join(",", simpleMap.keySet()).contains("SectionSelection");
}
```

Comment: He's looking for a faster way of doing this, and using `stream` the time of method execution is 64144400 in nanoTime and using `for` the nanoTime is 43600 ... is more finer, but 1.440x more slow

Comment: I was considering @Bangaram comment "This method is called for each and every action performed in my application" :)

Comment: @JoãoZarate - After going through the comments, I've updated my answer.